# WordPress Access

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I'm working on a website with a friend using `Wordpress` and we are trying to access the same WordPress account from both mine and his computer, so that we can work on the website together. We have tried to add each other as admins but can only access the new account from the computer the admin has been created on. Does anyone know how to do this?

By the way `wordpress` is run on `wampserver`

Comment: If it's running on a WAMP server, then only the person with the WAMP server can access it, unless you implement some sort of access through Bitnami or similar platforms.

Comment: If you have installed WAMP locally on one computer, it only works on that computer. You have to upload the website to the Internet before it can be accessed from somewhere else. Or, turn the computer into a server but that's probably a bit too advanced at this point.

Comment: @AdamA  Hi Adam, thanks would I definitely be able to acces through bitnami?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP server is for local development (like XAMP, LAMPP and MAMP). When you install WAMP and install Wordpress inside it, it can be only accessed from that computer. You can create multiple admin accounts on single Wordpress installation. (Do not use single admin account for both of you.)

However in this case, you can't access the **local** Wordpress installation with multiple computers. to do that you may have need to buy a domain and a hosting from a hosting provider. Then you can create two admin accounts and start developing.

Or, as JJJ suggested you can convert WAMP+Wordpress installed computer to a server, but its hard and I do not think it'll be a good idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is local. You can move the WordPress install onto a shared hosting relatively painlessly and cheaply then can collaboratively work on it.

Comment: Hi Mike, cheers what shared hosting platform would you recommend?

Comment: There are too many to go into here. I've used 1&1 before for very cheap hosting for development sites.

Compare general shared hosting: http://uk.pcmag.com/webcom/8310/guide/the-best-web-hosting-services-of-2017

If you're new to WordPress and need more help with set-up and management, a WordPress host may be best: http://uk.pcmag.com/web-site-hosting-services/46170/guide/the-best-wordpress-web-hosting-services-of-2017